# Content Security Policy nonce on style attribute being ignored

Tags: html, security, bootstrap-4, content-security-policy, nonce

I am setting content security policy up, and a vendor library (bootstap) is setting styles inline to display a dialog and Edge/Chromium is saying that the change has been declined.

My CSP header (example split onto separate lines for ease of reading) is:

```
default-src 'none'; 
script-src 'self' 'nonce-OGrJRYbkub0OVcGnjoCFDw/OF+bamLQddwgBEfu9HjE='; 
style-src 'self' 'nonce-OGrJRYbkub0OVcGnjoCFDw/OF+bamLQddwgBEfu9HjE='; 
style-src-attr 'self' 'nonce-OGrJRYbkub0OVcGnjoCFDw/OF+bamLQddwgBEfu9HjE='; 
img-src 'self' https://www.gravatar.com;
font-src 'self' 'nonce-OGrJRYbkub0OVcGnjoCFDw/OF+bamLQddwgBEfu9HjE=';
connect-src 'self';
prefetch-src 'self';
form-action 'self';
manifest-src 'self';
upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; report-to default;
```

As you can see, I have the `style-src-attr` set and my html is as follows:

```
<div id="large-right-modal" class="modal fade show" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="large-right-modal-label" nonce="OGrJRYbkub0OVcGnjoCFDw/OF+bamLQddwgBEfu9HjE=" aria-modal="true">
</div>
```

When I display this bootstrap modal, the library adds the inline style `style="display: block;"` and the browser gives me the error:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src-attr 'self' 'nonce-OGrJRYbkub0OVcGnjoCFDw/OF+bamLQddwgBEfu9HjE='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-TH1YO7Owtg52rPfkQs+Us6yN6exn7w99CdIBBm9BmMQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

This doesn't make much sense, the nonce is the same as that on the element being modified. The only thing that works is by adding `unsafe-inline` to the policy which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Nonce can be used in nonceable elements. At least in CSP level 2 this would mostly be restricted to <script> and <style>. The problem is that you have the style in an attribute, try moving to a style block or css file.

Comment: I believe that's acceptable; you can define a nonce on a tag otherwise you wouldn't be able to handle styles changed by JScript, or be able to use inline styles on a just a few specific places without using the catch all 'unsafe-inline'

Comment: Only [`<script>` and `<style>` are nonceable elements](http://csplite.com/csp/test187/). Handle styles by JScript is [allowed](https://csplite.com/csp/test64/#test) except `setAttribute("style", ...)` func. BTW, bootstarp uses CSP-safe way to add `style='display:block;'` and judging by `sha256-TH1YO7Owtg52rPfkQs+Us6yN6exn7w99CdIBBm9BmMQ=` - it's not `style='display:block;'` been blocked. The `font-src` directive covers `@font-face` construct - it's not html-element therefore `'nonce-value'` can't be applied. The `style-src-attr` directive is not support `'self'` and `'nonce-value'`.